# correcting concatenation query. C# and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, concatenation

I have a table in my data base with 4 columns `Specie` | `Price` | `Stock` | `Country`.
and two drop down list, the first is `Country` once the country is selected the second drop down Shows the `Specie` allocated to the country.
This all works well.

**The two drop down list that I have are**

1. `ddlcountry` for the user to select the country
2. and `DdPetPist` is the Specie list

**Problem**

I have select index change that shows 2 label's with `Price` and `Specie` selected.
problem being is that the label is not showing the correct print out of the country selected, I know its the query but I have tried several variations and can not seem to get it to work correct, advise or help will be much appreciated.

**Code with query below**

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selection_price = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
        string selection_stock = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
        string petPrice = string.Empty;
        string available = string.Empty;

        MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Price FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{0}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_price), cs);
        MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Stock FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_stock), cs);

        cs.Open();
        petPrice = Convert.ToString(cd_price.ExecuteScalar());
        available = Convert.ToString(cd_available.ExecuteScalar());
        cs.Close();

        PetPrice.Text = String.Format("Minimum Donation For A {0}  Is £{1}.", selection_price, petPrice);
        Availble.Text = String.Format("{0}'s Avalible {1} In Your Country.", selection_stock, available);
    }
```

Comment: `...WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_price...` Do you mean *"Where specie = selection_price"* ? and similarly the second one..

Comment: I get where your going, but it dose not work

Comment: Actually this was not a suggestion to change the code - it was a question - Do you on purpose take the *second* parameter {1} which happen to be "selection_price" and use it in WHERE query?

Comment: the first {0} will output the Specie, the second {1} will output the price of the selected Specie. i have updated the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Price FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{0}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_price), cs);
MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Stock FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_stock), cs);
```

You give two parameters to your query when there is only one in the string. You want to match the `Specie` column with the `ddlcountry` value ... I think you hit the wrong dropdownlist.

You should use parameterized queries :

```
MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Price FROM Animals WHERE Specie = @specie");
m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@specie", ddlcountry.Text);
```

[Link to documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html)

Comment: dose not seem to work, I will keep trying though .. thank you

Comment: .... I did not give you working code. I copied your wrong code and told you what to do : i don't know the name of the right dropdownlist to get the specie value. And then, i showed you how to do queries with parameters in the good way. You still have to change `ddlcountry.Text` in this piece of code.